# Internationalization with Titanium's ListView

Tags: listview, internationalization, titanium

I am getting repeated values from my ListView Items (it's Like text over text).

This is my problem (I am not sure if the image will be uploaded):

[image: ListView]

And my ListView code is:

```
  <ListView id="listView" defaultItemTemplate="template" onItemclick="menuOptions">

                <!-- The Templates tag sets the ListView's templates property -->
                <Templates>

                    <!-- Define your item templates within the Templates tags or use the
                         Require tag to include a view that only contains an ItemTemplate -->
                    <ItemTemplate name="template">
                        <ImageView bindId="pic" id="icon" />
                        <Label id="petLabel" />
                        <Label id="needleLable" />
                        <Label id="heightControl"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                </Templates>

                <ListSection>
                    <ListItem id="petLabel" val="mascota" pic:image="/images/menu/footprint.png"/>
                    <ListItem id="needleLable" val="vacuna" pic:image="/images/menu/pet.png"/>
                    <ListItem id="heightControl" val="estadistica" pic:image="/images/menu/pet.png"/>
                </ListSection>
       </ListView>
```

In the files I used for internationzalition (platform/android/values-en and values-es) I have got this:

String.xml

```
<resources>
<!--Menu -->
    <string name="itemPet">Pet Profile</string>
    <string name="itemNeedle">Needle</string>
    <string name="itemHeight">Height Control</string>

</resources>
```

and the values-es

```
<resources>
     <!--Menu -->
    <string name="itemPet">Mascota</string>
    <string name="itemNeedle">Ver Vacunas</string>
    <string name="itemHeight">Control de peso</string>


</resources>
```

And finally the .tss files where I call the text to show :

```
'#petLabel':{   
    textAlign: Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
    text:L('itemPet'),
    font:{
        fontSize:30, 
        fontWeight:'bold',
        fontFamily:'clear-sans.light'
    }
}

'#needleLable':{    
    textAlign: Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
    text: L('itemNeedle'),   
    font:{
        fontSize:30, 
        fontWeight:'bold',
        fontFamily:'clear-sans.light'
    }
}

'#heightControl':{  
    textAlign: Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
    text:L('itemHeight'),
    font:{
        fontSize:30, 
        fontWeight:'bold',
        fontFamily:'clear-sans.light'
    }   
}
```

I don't know why this happened, I have tried many things and I am not able to solve, any thought will be usefull.

Thank you.

Additional information:

I did an alert that get the event when I click the ListItem, the alert return this:

{properties={height=100dp, accessoryType=0, textAlign=center, font={fontWeight=bold, fontSize=30, fontFamily=clear-sans.light}, title=Ver Vacunas, val=vacuna, id=needleLable}, pic={image=/images/menu/pet.png}}

The title show the correct text, however the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in the Oficial's documentation: 
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Localization

You can specify the Localization via XML attribute.

So I modify my .xml code:

```
    <ListView id="listView" defaultItemTemplate="template" onItemclick="menuOptions">

                <!-- The Templates tag sets the ListView's templates property -->
                <Templates>

                    <!-- Define your item templates within the Templates tags or use the
                         Require tag to include a view that only contains an ItemTemplate -->
                    <ItemTemplate name="template">
                        <ImageView bindId="pic" id="icon" />
                        <Label  bindId="label" id="petLabel" />

                    </ItemTemplate>

                </Templates>

    <ListSection>
                    <ListItem label:text="L('itemPet')" val="mascota" pic:image="/images/menu/footprint.png"/>
                    <ListItem label:text="L('itemNeedle')" val="vacuna" pic:image="/images/menu/pet.png"/>
                    <ListItem label:text="L('itemHeight')" title="" val="estadistica" pic:image="/images/menu/pet.png"/>

    </ListSection>
       </ListView>
```

And now it's working fine this few words make the magic : **label:text="L('itemPet')"**

Answer (score 0):

This could be a layout problem.

try specifying layout='vertical' in ListView and ListSection elements.

Something like this:

```
<ListView id="listView" defaultItemTemplate="template" onItemclick="menuOptions" layout='vertical'>
....
 <ListSection layout='vertical'>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Funtik, I tried specifying layout='vertical' in ListView and ListSection elements but unfortunately it did not work